# How to use setTimeOut and setInterval in one function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Write a function customSetInterval (funcToExecute, interval)
     using recursion and setTimeout,
     which will repeat the functionality of the setInterval built-in method
     the setInterval built-in method takes two arguments:
     the first argument is a function that runs at a given time interval
     the second argument is the time interval in milliseconds.

```
 function to call:
 function executeMe () {
     console.log ('123')
 }

 example of calling your function:
 customSetInterval (executeMe, 1000)
 as a result, the 123 line will be displayed in the console every second
```

Pulled from comment below:

```
function customSetInterval(funcToExecute, interval) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        function executeMe() {
            console.log('123');
            customSetInterval();
        }
    }, 1000)
};
customSetInterval(funcToExecute, 1000);
```

Comment: are you asking us to solve it or did you try anything at all?

Comment: yeah I tried it many times but failed

Comment: please add whatever you have tried

Comment: my last solution but ig gives me error

Comment: function customSetInterval(funcToExecute, interval) {
 setTimeout(function(){
  function executeMe(){
   console.log('123');
   customSetInterval();
  }
 }, 1000)

};
customSetInterval(funcToExecute, 1000);

Comment: add it to the question

Comment: sorry I fogort to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```js
function executeMe() {
  console.log('123');
}

function customSetInterval(fn, time) {
   setTimeout(function() {
    fn();
    customSetInterval(fn, time)
   }, time);
}


customSetInterval (executeMe, 1000);
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try this one:

```
function executeMe() {
    console.log('123');
}

function customSetInterval (executeMe, second){
    try {
        setInterval(executeMe, second);
    } catch (error) {
        setTimeOut(executeMe, second);
    }
}

customSetInterval("executeMe()", 1000);
```